# Border issue in fluid layout on fixed position

Tags: javascript, html, css

My problem with aligning the middle border in fluid layout. Initially the header and content middle borders are fine, but when page scroll comes the content portion is adjusted and the border is  misaligned. Anybody have solution for this? Im ready to use Javascript, if there is a solution.

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="hdrSectionleft">
        <p>First Title</p>
    </div>
    <div class="hdrSectionright">
        <p>Second Title</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="contentLeft">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...</div>
    <div class="contentRight">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, p {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.header {
    Position:fixed;
    top:50px;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    background-color:#eee;
}
.hdrSectionleft {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    border-right:1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    height:40px;
}
.hdrSectionleft p, .hdrSectionright p {
    padding:12px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:14px;
}
.hdrSectionright {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    height:40px;
}
.content {
    Position:absolute;
    top:90px;
    max-height:150px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    border-top:1px solid #ccc;
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    overflow:auto;
}
.contentLeft {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    border-right:1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:10px;
}
.contentRight {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    padding:10px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Here is the link to my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tyas/cFZ3d/

Comment: The problem is caused by scrollbar. `.contentLeft{width:52%;}
.contentRight{width:48%;}`
, maybe this will help!

Comment: The challenge is, it should be align with or without page scroll and any resolution. I can add 52%, but again problem if there is no page scroll

Answer (score 2):

I think you want [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cFZ3d/5/)

```
.header{Position:fixed; margin-top:50px; display:block; width:100%; height:auto; background-color:#eee; }

.content{Position:absolute; top:140px; max-height:150px; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;   border-top:1px solid #ccc; width:100%; box-sizing:border-box; 
overflow:auto;}
```

I have changed something in your fiddle. Please check this one.

thank you.

Comment: Friend, the header middle border and content middle border should be aligned with and without scroll bar. Currently the page scroll pulls the fluid layout and causing the alignment issue

Comment: No the alignment is missing on various resolution/resizing, and no pixel value used in the layout

Comment: Your black border is moving when resizing the screen

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the vertical scrollbars which appear when the content area reaches it's max height

If you must have the scroll only on the content section - then you'll need javascript to detect when to adjust the with of the content.

How about setting the max-height on the header + content by put them in a container div:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/cFZ3d/2/)**

```
.container
{
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 194px; /* 44px header + max 150px for content */
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: The header is fixed position, sometimes the content will have less or more text, but the middle border should align with header

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div class="scroll"><div class="header">
    <div class="hdrSectionleft"><p>First Title</p></div>
    <div class="hdrSectionright"><p>Second Title</p></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="contentLeft">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</div>
    <div class="contentRight">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</div>
</div>
</div>
```

css

```
body, p{padding:0; margin:0;}
.header{Position:fixed; top:50px; display:block; width:100%; height:40px; background-color:#eee;z-index: 1;}
.hdrSectionleft{float:left; width:50%; border-right:1px solid #ccc; box-sizing:border-box; height:40px;}
.hdrSectionleft p, .hdrSectionright p{padding:12px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;}
.hdrSectionright{float:left; width:50%; height:40px;}

.content{Position:absolute; top:90px; max-height:150px; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; border-top:1px solid #ccc; width:100%; box-sizing:border-box; 
}


.contentLeft{float:left; width:50%; border-right:1px solid #ccc; box-sizing:border-box; padding:10px;}
.contentRight{float:left; width:50%; padding:10px; box-sizing:border-box;}
.scroll
{overflow:auto;
    max-height:150px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but header should be fixed, only the content portion should have the scroll

Answer (score 0):

Here is an other solution for your request:

Style Sheet:

```
<style>
body, p{padding:0; margin:0 auto;}
td p{padding:12px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;}
.content{border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; border-top:1px solid #ccc; width:50%; box-sizing:border-box; }
.content div{max-height:150px; height:150px;overflow:auto; padding:10px }
</style>
```

HTML Code:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr height="40">
<td bgcolor="#eee" width="50%" headers="40" style="border-right:1px solid #ccc;box-sizing:border-box;"><p>First Title</p></td>
<td bgcolor="#eee" width="50%" height="40"><p>Second Title</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="content" valign="top" style="border-right:1px solid #ccc; padding:0">
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.
</div>
</td>
<td class="content" style="padding:0">
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this, but there should be one scroll for the content, not separate scrolls

Answer (score 0):

There might be one Easier, best & Semantic solution which is Using Tables for tabular data.

Otherwise need to use some stuffy javascript

Comment: I have used the tables, but have got two scroll, do you have any examples?